# Date Formats Not Working

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm using Teradata as my SQL client and have been playing around with date format formula.

Many seem to not work.

Here's a sample query that does work:

```
EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP(FORMAT 'yyyy-mm')(char(7)) AS YEAR_MONTH,
```

But I found some ways that I thought would be easier to remember yet none seem to work:

```
DATE_FORMAT(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP,'%M-%Y')
```

Gives syntax error "EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP does not match defined type name"

Then tried (My favourite potential solution):

```
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP) AS YEAR_MONTH,
```

Gives syntax error "Expected something like DAY keyword or HOUR keyword or MINUTE keyword between "(" and YEAR_MONTH.

Then tried, just to see if it works:

```
CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP),  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP))  AS YEAR_MONTH,
```

Gives syntax error "expected soemthing between "(" and EXTRACT keyword.

I read about these functions online and don;t understand why they are failing. Am I missing something?

Comment: A bit nitpicking: Teradata is a SQL database *server*. It's not a "SQL client". The "client" is the program you use to *access* the Teradata server.

Comment: So, would the Teradata interface be considered the client then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge and testing the following are not a native functions or ODBC extension as of Teradata 14.0:

```
DATE_FORMAT(EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP,'%M-%Y')
CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP),  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP))  AS YEAR_MONTH,
```

'YEAR_MONTH' is not a valid INTERVAL type for use with the `EXTRACT` function here:

```
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP) AS YEAR_MONTH,
```

Consider the following instead:

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP) || '-' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMPE) AS YEAR_MONTH,
```

Although your first solution is probably the most flexible in terms of formatting options available within the database.

Comment: Oh, so it's not me it's my SQL client, Teradata?

Comment: Also, according to this link YEAR_MONTH is a valid interval type? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_extract.asp - see it at the bottom of the table? The last solution you offer - would that output still be a date or justa  string?

Comment: The link you provide is for MySQL and not Teradata. YEAR_MONTH is not supported by Teradata.The last result will be a STRING as a result of the concatenation operation being performed.

Comment: Concatenating the EXTRACTs will result in lots of blanks and a single digit month :-) You will have to add a FORMAT, thus it's better to keep the (FORMAT 'yyyy-mm')(char(7)). Or "EXTRACT(YEAR FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP) * 100 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EVENT_GMT_TIMESTAMP)" for a numeric result.